# Restart docker with different environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a docker-compose that has

```
myimage:
  image: myimage:latest
  environment:
    MY_VAR: "something"
```

the container uses MY_VAR internally, and sometimes in automated testing I'd like to restart that specific container with a different MY_VAR (to simulate a process restart with different environment variable settings)

Is there a way to do this while keeping the rest of the docker-compose container up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like @robin.thoni said, would need to recreate the container to change the `MY_VAR` value, but you could make the process simpler by using a environment var in the compose YML, like this:

```
    myimage:
      image: myimage:latest
      environment:
        - MY_VAR: ${A_ENV_VAR}
```

And running the container like this:

```
A_ENV_VAR=test docker-compose run myimage
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, you have to recreate a container, as environment variables are given in the `run` command (even with a docker-compose).